# Redirect with react-router-native V4

Tags: react-native, react-router

I am putting together an app using React-Native and React-Router.  I have a couple of pages with navigation that all seems to work as expected.

In my login component, I wanted to redirect once the user is authenticated, and this is where I seem to be stuck.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import {connect} from 'react-redux'
import {StyleSheet, View, TextInput, Image, TouchableOpacity, Text} from 'react-native'
import {Redirect} from 'react-router-native'

import {fetchAuth} from './actions/login.actions'

export class LoginForm extends Component {
    async onLoginPress() {
        this.props.fetchAuth(this.state)
        if (this.props.loginState.authStatus > 0) {
            console.log("Logged in");
            return (
                <Redirect to="/logged_in_page"/>
            )
        } else {
            console.log("Not logged in");
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <View>
                    <TextInput
                        onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({username: text})}
                    />
                    <TextInput
                        onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({password: text})}
                    />
                </View>
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.onLoginPress.bind(this)}>
                    <Image
                        source={require('./images/btn.png')}
                    >
                        <Text >Login</Text>
                    </Image>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
        )
    }
}
```

Note: My IDE is telling me that it cannot resolve "Redirect" in the import statement, but it also says that for the "Switch" in my App.js but that seems to be working without problem.

I get to the two console.logs without issue, but the re-direct isn't doing anything.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<Redirect />` is a component.

You have to place it inside your `render()` method and render it whenever you need that redirection.

Something like this

```
export class LoginForm extends Component {
    async onLoginPress() {
        this.props.fetchAuth(this.state)
    }

    render() {
        if (this.props.loginState.authStatus > 0) {
            return <Redirect to="/logged_in_page"/>
        } 

        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <View>
                    <TextInput
                        onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({username: text})}
                    />
                    <TextInput
                        onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({password: text})}
                    />
                </View>
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.onLoginPress.bind(this)}>
                    <Image
                        source={require('./images/btn.png')}
                    >
                        <Text >Login</Text>
                    </Image>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
        )
    }
}
```